# Mavensmate doesn't get the correct metadata index when refreshing

Tags: metadata, mavensmate

Whenever I refresh the metadata index for the 'CustomObject' Metadata type, an incorrect set of objects comes up. For example, I have a custom object named Account Address, which tracks the addresses of accounts. When I refresh, mavensmate does not see the Account Address object under the CustomObject folder.

[image]

I tried to edit the package.xml manually to contain a * in a member field inside of CustomObject, but MavensMate only reverts the file back to the previous state.

How do I use MavensMate to download all CustomObject metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very important to make sure that you don't have the 'Ignore managed metadata' box checked. This box is found under MavensMate's settings icon.

Once you have unchecked it, make sure to refresh your metadata index.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting a star (*) in the package.xml, can you try and put the actual sObject API name and see if that works?